# awk to replace value in specific column

Tags: awk

I have the following line:

```
pr: 10.00    20.00
```

I want to replace the third column with "00.00" while preserving tabs and spaces on the line.There's a space between the first and second column, and a tab between second and third column.  The following command works EXCEPT it inserts a tab between the first and second column:

awk '$1=="pr:"{OFS="\t"; $3="00.00"}1' mydata.txt > out

How can I keep the space and tabs as they appear in the original line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sub` for it:

```
$ awk '{sub(/20.00/,"00.00")}1' file
pr: 10.00    00.00
```

or if it's the last field:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^ \t]+$/,"00.00")}1' file
pr: 10.00    00.00
```

**Edit**: If you're using GNU awk, `split`the record and store the separators:

```
$ awk '
{ 
    n=split($0,a,FS,seps)                     # save delim spaces to seps
    a[3]="00.00"                              # changes to a
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                         # loop to n
        printf "%s%s",a[i],(i==n?ORS:seps[i]) # print a and seps
}' file
pr: 10.00    00.00
```

Comment: Can I keep the column number instead?  The reason is that the value of $20.00 changes sometimes. I'm changing multiple lines in a file, and it's not just one line I'm updating.

Answer (score 1):

Simple ***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F'\t| ' '{$NF="00.00"}1' input
```

The output:

```
pr: 10.00    00.00
```

Comment: Didn't think of that at all. ++

Comment: @JamesBrown, yeah, that's why we like AWK, for his simplicity and power ))

Comment: `\t| ` = `[\t ]` or even `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` but in any case it effectively behaves the same as the default `FS` and that would replace all tabs with blank chars and the OP specifically said (s)he wants to preserve spacing.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your original script would just be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1~/^pr:/{$2="00.00"} 1' mydata.txt > out
```

Comment: 1) your script doesn't even work. Hint: "single quote". 2) the OP wanted to preserve space as well. How that?

Comment: 1) quote removed, 2) The OP said `There's a space between the first and second column, and a tab between second and third column. ` So the OP has a space between `pr:` and the first number and then a tab between the 2 pairs of numbers - that is what my script will output.

Comment: I'm not stopping him from doing so if he wants. Not sure where you're coming from.

Comment: Thanks Ed - Never thought that I could solve the problem in a one-line script!  Thank you all for helping with my very first awk script.